# Create combobox in .xls files using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a question, it is possible to create combo box using the Apache POI library?

Comment: You should go back to your old questions and select an answer for them by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer that helped most. Otherwise people might no longer help you.

Answer (score 0):

A good example is here

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/poi/XLCellDropDown.shtml

Comment: Please consider adding some context to the answer, in case the linked url won't be available anymore.